# jQuery AJAX - Pass value to a PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a div which includes a data-id value. I want jQuery to detect when the div is clicked and then send or store the data-id value in a PHP file. My code is below, the click is detected and the data-id value is stored but I'm receiving an error for obtaining the data-id value in the php file, how do I solve this? I just want the value '189' to be stored in the 'player.php' file.

**myteam.php** file

```
<div class="goalkeeper">

    <div class="player" data-id="189">
        <div class="shirt">
            <img src="_img/kits/10/gk.png" alt="Football Shirt">
        </div>

        <p class="pname">Alisson</p>
        <p class="ppoints">0</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

**player.js** file

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.player').click(function() {

    var pid = $(this).data("id");

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "player.php?",
        data: pid,
        success: function( pid ){
            alert(pid);
          }
        });
    });

});
```

**player.php** file

```
if(session_id() == '' || !isset($_SESSION)) {
    // session isn't started
    session_name('FantasyKicks');
    session_start();
}

$pid = $_POST['pid'];

echo $pid;
```

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: 'Undefined index: pid' for '$pid = $_POST['pid'];'  - I realise that before I click the button there will be no value so the error is fine, but when I click the button, the error remains.

Answer (score 0):

Change your AJAX to identify the `pid` (and you don't need the `?` on the URL):

```
    $('.player').click(function() {

    var pid = $(this).data("id");

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "player.php",
        data: { pid: pid } // the first `pid` is the identifier, the second is your value
        success: function( pid ){
            alert(pid);
          }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Still getting the same error for '$pid = $_POST['pid'];' - "Undefined index: pid"

Comment: Open the developer's tools in your browser and watch the AJAX request/response. Make sure you're not sending an empty value.

Comment: Try to replace `$(this).data("id")` by `$(this).attr("data-id")`, also add `console.log(pid)` after and same in php through `var_dump($_POST)` to see what php script receive.

Comment: @Lounis tested with `$(this).data("id")` worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Okay, I haven't used the dev tool to see the AJAX request/response before so not entirely sure what i'm looking out for. I'm using Chrome and looking under the 'Network' tab, the preview and response are both showing '189' which is correct. Under the 'Headers' and then the 'Response Headers' the 'content-length' is 3. So everything seems fine from here but is there anything specific I need to look for?

Comment: Based on what you're saying it seems to be working. It is working for me as well. No error in the console means that `$_POST['pid']` is populated.

Comment: The alert in the success function works fine but how do I then use the value in the 'player.php' file? '$pid = $_POST['pid'];' is still getting an error for me

Comment: You can use it however you'd like to. For instance, you can use it in a query.

Comment: You have to remember that you cannot load the PHP file in your browser and expect the variable to be set because you set the variable with AJAX. You send the request to the PHP file, let it do everything you want, and wait for it to return the response.

Comment: [Read this](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html).